# My first code in JQUERY. (.HTML)

Tags: jquery

i am writing first code in JQUERY language.

JQUERY code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#firemni').click(function(){
        $('tr#firma').html("<td width='22%'>Firma *</td>  <td> <input type='text' name='name' required></td>");
    });
</script>
```

HTML: 
...

```
<input id="firemni" type="radio" name="group2" value="Firma"> Firemni zakaznik
<tr id="firma2"></tr>
```

These codes show me no error. I don't know where is error, what I do wrong?
THX a lot for your time.

Comment: In html you mentioned tr id is firma2 but in jquey you mentioned $('tr#firma') it should be $('tr#firma2')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#firemni').click(function(){
    $('tr#firma2').html("<td width='22%'>Firma *</td>  <td> <input type='text' name='name' required></td>");
    });
});
```

or if you like, post ur script under the html tags.

Comment: It´s work. I need put the code between $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: :) 
just remember that html tags must be distinguish first before the scripts

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First add any version of `jquery` I am using latest verion of `jquery` here

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#firemni').click(function(){
            $('tr#firma2').html("<td width='22%'>Firma *</td>  <td> <input type='text' name='name' required></td>");
            // firma2 in place of firma, check id of tr
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up in calling your `id` you've named your `<tr id='firma2'>` you should call it in your jquery `$('#firma2')`

**Change it to this:**

---

```
$('#firma2').html("<td width='22%'>Firma *</td>  <td> <input type='text' name='name' required></td>");
```